# Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код, чтобы он правильно считал обратную матрицу

Tags: c++, матрицы

Я использовал код с сайта (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adjoint-inverse-matrix/) и переделал его для своей программы. Но он не работает. Я выяснил что функция `determinant()` всегда возвращает `0`.

```cpp
void getCofactor(Matrix A, Matrix temp, int p, int q, int m)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < m; col++)
        {
            if (row != p && col != q)
            {
                temp.matrix[i][j++] = A.matrix[row][col];
                if (j == m - 1)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

float determinant(Matrix A, int m)
{
    float D = 0;
    if (m == 1) 
        return A.matrix[0][0]; 
    Matrix temp(A.n, 0);
    int sign = 1;
    for (int f = 0; f < m; f++)
    {
        getCofactor(A, temp, 0, f, m);
        D += sign * A.matrix[0][f] * determinant(temp, m - 1);
        sign = -sign;
    }
    return D;
}

void adjoint(Matrix A, Matrix adj)
{
    if (A.n == 1)
    {
        adj.matrix[0][0] = 1;
        return;
    }
    int sign = 1;
    Matrix temp(A.n, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.n; j++)
        {
            getCofactor(A, temp, i, j, A.n);
            sign = ((i + j) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;
            adj.matrix[j][i] = (sign) * determinant(temp, A.n - 1);
        }
    }
}

 bool inverse(Matrix A, Matrix invers)
{
    float det = determinant(A, A.n);
    if (det == 0)
    {
        cout << "Singular matrix, can't find its inverse";
        return false;
    }
    Matrix adj(A.n, 0);
    adjoint(A, adj);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.n; j++) {
            invers.matrix[i][j] = adj.matrix[i][j] / float(det);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < A.n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.n; j++)
            cout << invers.matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Вот мои конструкторы, но от них скорее всего ничего не зависит:

```cpp
Matrix::Matrix(int _n) : n(_n)
{
    matrix = new float* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new float[n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 15;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int _n, int _m) : n(_n)
{
    matrix = new float* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new float[n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = _m;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& _ob)
{
    n = _ob.n;
    matrix = new float* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new float[n];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = _ob.matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete[] matrix[i];
    }
    delete[] matrix;
}
```

(Возможно я что-то пропустил или не так поменял, но я уже не в силах это исправить)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы в `getCofactor` модифицируете аргумент `temp`. А он является копией реального аргумента. И после окончания этой функции временная матрица `temp` исчезает.

Решается изменением типов аргументов `A` и `temp` на ссылку :

```
void getCofactor(Matrix & A, Matrix & temp, int p, int q, int m)
```

*В коде по ссылке https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adjoint-inverse-matrix/ все матрицы передаются указателями, а вы всё передаёте копиями.*